# Unable to run many Commands in Vim's visual mode externally

Tags: vim

I have the following commands in a README file:

```
./Setup ...
./Setup ...
./Setup ...
```

I want to run them by selecting the codes visually and then running them.

I run unsuccessfully

```
: '<,'> !
```

**Current code after Luc's comments in his answer**

**My code in .vimrc which I have not managed to get to work:**

```
vmap <silent> <leader>v y:exe '!'.join(split(@", "\n"),';')<cr>
```

I am trying to make make a keyboard combination for

```
v yy
```

**How can you get the above command work**, such that you can run file's commands directly in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be oversimplifying things, but why not just do:

```
:e README
:%!bash
```

This filters the current file through bash, executing each line as a command.  The current buffer is replaced by the output of running all of the commands in the file.

It might be helpful to do a `:w RESULTS` to save it as another file first, so you don't accidentally overwrite the original:

```
:e README
:w RESULTS
:%!bash
```

You had said you wanted to do this with a visual selection, which would work just as well  After you select what you want to execute, type `:`.  `'<,'>` will automatically be prepended to the current command.  `'<` is the mark of the beginning of the current selection, whereas `'>` is the mark at the end of the current selection.  You can just run just those commands you have selected just like above:

```
:'<,'>!bash
```

This will replace just the selected commands with the output of executing those commands.

Answer (score 5):

- First select your text,
- then copy it with `y`,
- and finally, you can execute:

  :exe '!'.join(split(@", "\n"),';')

Comment: Your command works! Thank you. I wonder if there are any shorter way to do the same. It is difficult for me to remember the command.

Comment: You can define a mapping: -> :vnoremap whatevercombo y:exe '!'.join(split(@", "\n"),';')<cr>

Comment: @Luc: Could you give an example of a combo. I am new in making them. I put unsuccessfully <tab-a> as a combo, that is press TAB and A to get the last part.

Comment: It will be <tab>a. We put two (or more) keys within the angle brackets only with keys like *c*trl, *s*hift, and *a*lt (/*m*eta) to denote the keys are pressed together (-> <c-a>, <s-e>, <c-s-z>, <a-del>, etc.)

Comment: I made the following unsuccessful code % vmap <silent> <leader>v :exe '!'.join(split(@", "\n"),';')<cr> % I get "no range allowed", although I have only % echo masi % in my the selection of visual mode.

Comment: You forgot to yank the current selection.

Comment: @Luc: I have now % vmap <silent> <leader>v y:exe '!'.join(split(@", "\n"),';')<cr> % I get "no range allowed", although I have only %. I am unable to get the code to work. How can you get the code to work?

Comment: As I said: :vnoremap <leader>v y:exe '!'.join(split(@", "\n"),';')<cr>

Comment: @Luc: I have tested the combinations now ...<leader>v XXXX:exe ... where XXXX has been a, <a> and <c-a>. I go to the visual mode and press a or C-a: nothing happens. --- Do you know why?

Comment: This mapping has only one purpose : execute all lines in an external shell. What do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: @Luc: I want to execute all selected lines of the file in Visual mode.

Comment: Then XXX is y and nothing else.